# Angular 4 - How to get data to database with a parameter

Tags: php, angular

I would like to know how to pass parameter from url to php using http service.

**service:**

```
  getEmployeesById(data) {
     let datas = JSON.stringify({'id':data});
      return this.http.get('http://localhost/employees/?p=editEmployees', datas)
    .map(response => response.json() );
  }
```

**component:**

```
ngOnInit() {
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((queryParams: Params) => {
  let userId = queryParams['id'];
  this.employeesServices.getEmployeesById(userId)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.result = data
    });
});
```

}

**PHP : http://localhost/employees/?p=editEmployees**

```
$editEmployees = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM $employeesTable WHERE emp_id = '".$_GET['id']."' ");
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($editEmployees);
$emp[] = $rows;
echo json_encode($emp);
```

-I created a mysqli query that gets the employee id.
-Then in component, I fetched the emp id from url param(id) like this

```
this.employeesServices.getEmployeesById(userId);
```

My problem is, I dont know If I am passing the data correct.

I display the data in html using

```
{{ result.first_name }}
```

but I cant get it right.

Comment: do you get console errors , after doing a post is the data reaching your server

Comment: Try: `{{ result?.first_name }}` with a question mark.

Comment: I always get this error (core.es5.js:1020 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0) I dont know how to properly read the PASSED data in php. and transfer it back to component and display it to HTML

Comment: What json you are getting in response.

Comment: I tried {{ result?.first_name }}, but no luck.

Comment: @alankar, actually I still cant get a correct response yet

Comment: AHHHHH I SEE MY PROBLEM IS I CANT GET THE PASSED DATA FROM ANGULAR TO MY PHP, I CANT USE $_GET['id'], and $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
  $request = json_decode($postdata);
  if ($request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can send it in the query string like you already sent `p=editEmployees` as parameter in the query string. You can simply append another parameter in the query string like this

```
getEmployeesById(data) { // as data is userId so simply append it 
      return this.http.get('http://localhost/employees/?p=editEmployees&id='+ data)
    .map(response => response.json() );
  }
```